# Error "Invalid comparison operator in dependency: >=" when installing R package from GitHub

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to install package "webr" from GitHub in R (v3.5.3) and get this error:

```
devtools::install_github("cardiomoon/webr")
```

> ```
> > Downloading GitHub repo cardiomoon/webr@master
> >
> > Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
> >
> >  Invalid comparison operator in dependency: >=
> ```

I could install 'webr' from CRAN repository without errors, but I need it from GitHub, because otherwise it does not contain the "PieDonut()" function to make these beautiful plots:

https://rpubs.com/cardiomoon/398623

The error seems to go back to some leading whitespaces in older "devtools" versions.

https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1247

I'm using the latest "devtools" package (v2.0.2) installed from CRAN repository, where this problem should be solved already.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There was a small issue in their `DESCRIPTION` file. I fixed this and wrote a pull request. Until they accept the PR or fix the problem themselves, you can install the package from my fork:

```
devtools::install_github("JBGruber/webr")
```

### Update

Should be fixed. `devtools::install_github("cardiomoon/webr")` should work now.